# Realtime creation of csssprites in .NET

Tags: asp.net, css-sprites

Has anyone created a 'realtime' csssprite generator for .NET ?

I want one or more directories of images that get loaded at runtime and the css is automatically generated.

Comment: No...but that sounds like a fun project

Comment: Don't you think you should rephrase the question to be a little more specific? You are open to "Yes" and "No" answers. What is actually what you don't know how to do?

Comment: @voyager - feel free to answer 'no' or 'yes' if you don't mind getting downvoted :) but your answer below is what i was looking for

Comment: also i wanted to start some kind of 'discussion' on here about realtime creation. all the other css-sprites posts i've seen on SO have referred to tools which work once but aren't very 'DRY' friendly

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You'll find it at
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/cssspritegenerator.aspx

Unlike Microsoft's attempt at sprites, with this package you don't have to change the way your images are stored and how they are shown. You simply add the .dll and configure the package in your web.config with a few lines.

This package also lets you resize images on the fly, compress them and other good things.

Answer (score 1):

[Is this what you are looking for?](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2008/03/05/css-sprite-for-asp-net.aspx)
It's the closest I found to a baked solution.

Comment: that looks good. actually i'm integrating it into an existing image caching/dynamic css sprite project. i wanted to a) see what others had done for code reuse/ideas/caveats b) figure out whether i should try to fit my icons nicely (as if they were float:left) or just have them all in a row

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally something official...

Not clear yet if it'll make it into the core ASP.NET framework but here's a Microsoft codeplex project for csssprites :

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50869

if you like it - use it - or just like the idea then add a comment. I think this would be a great thing to have in the ASP.NET framework. Have not personally used it (I had to invent the wheel myself) but its got good reviews.

---

It includes the following components:

- API for automatically generating sprites and inline images
- Controls and helpers which provide a convenient way of calling into the API

Features Added in Second Release:

- A CSS linking control for Web Forms (selects the proper CSS file for the user's browser, but does not display an image)
- Using custom folder paths other than App_Sprites
- Changing the tiling direction of sprite images
- Merging the generated CSS with a user's own CSS

Features under consideration for future releases:

- Automatically selecting the most efficient sprite background colour
- Automatically minifying the rendered CSS
- Compiling against .NET 3.5